# JSF Beans not accessable when deployed as war

Tags: java, spring, jsf, javabeans, war

I ran into a Strange Problem. I'm currently working on a project with the following configuration:

- Spring Framwork for data services
- JSF and Vaadin as web Framwork (2 seperated subcontexts)
- Tomcat 7 as application Container
- Spring EL resolver

When I deploy this application to my Tomcat Server everything works fine. When I build the application as a war-file with maven and deploy this war file on my Tomcat (the same tomcat!) the Vaadin frontend works fine, but in the JSF all Tags with values from beans stay empty. Tags with just plain text in it are processed correctly.

My biggest Problem is, that I don't get any exception. I'm also a bit confused that I also don't get an exception, when I try to access non-existing beans in my eclipse-deployed environment no error occurs, just no output is produced at that point.
I raised all Log Levels to max, but in the logs everything seems to be fine.

So, has anybody an idea, how to get JSF to display errors, when beans are not accessable and why there are difference when I deploy directly from eclipse or from a war file?

Thanks in advance!

nclaasen

Comment: Are the beans managed by JSF `@ManagedBean` or by Spring `@Component`? I'd suspect Spring EL resolver.

Comment: They are `@ManagedBean` annotated. I'll have a try changing them to `@Component`